# migrate MongoDB container service - mongodump command not found

Tags: cloud-foundry, mongodump, swisscomdev

I am trying to migrate my MongoDB container by following [the Swisscom tutorial](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/migrate-mongodb-to-kubernetes-based-mongodb.html).
I am currently stuck because I cannot do the `mongodump` command

```
$ mongodump --host localhost:13000 --authenticationDatabase <old-db-database> -u <old-db-username> -d <old-db-database>
Enter password: <old-db-password>
```

I tried to connect in SSH and execute the command but it didn't work.

```
U:\Documents\cf-env-master>cf ssh proxy-app -L 13000:2xtorvw9ys7tg9pc.service.consul:49642
vcap@ff9e229f-d570-4c6e-52fd-0a45:~$
vcap@ff9e229f-d570-4c6e-52fd-0a45:~$
vcap@ff9e229f-d570-4c6e-52fd-0a45:~$ mongodump --host localhost:13000 --authenticationDatabase Po1CA54gQdhmtCTa -u z2WScqr5y06j4ncx -d Po1CA54gQdhmtCTa
bash: mongodump: command not found
```

Mongo is correctly installed locally. I can access `mongo`, `mongodump` and `mongorestore`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must execute mongodump locally, not on the app container. The ssh connection is only opened to establish a tunnel (kind of a tcp port forwarding). The rest of the commands need to be executed in a separate terminal locally.

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial it says:

> Now that we’re connected, we can dump the old database using
>   mongodump. Open a new terminal and run the following command:

```
mongodump --host localhost:13000 --authenticationDatabase <old-db-database> -u <old-db-username> -d <old-db-database>
```

So please leave the terminal with the tunnel open while running the `mongodump` in a second terminal.